# element rename after flat file conversion

Tags: regex, xslt

I actually have a hard time describing the title, so let me just tell you what I have :

My XML was originally a flat file and has been converted to XML for me to play around with. Below is a bit simplified of the original XML:

```
<Elements>
    <ElementBegin value="e1"/>
    <ElementBegin value="e2"/>
    <String>Some Blabla</String>
    <ElementEnd value="e2"/>
    <ElementBegin value="e2"/>
    <String>Some other Blabla</String>
    <ElementEnd value="e2"/>
    <ElementBegin value="e5"/>
    <String>Some more Blabla</String>
    <ElementEnd value="e5"/>
    <ElementEnd value="e1"/>
</Elements>
```

Is there a way to simply 'rename' `<ElementBegin value="e1"/>` to `<e1>` and `<ElementEnd value="e1"/>` to `</e1>` using a regular expression or something? Or any other approach that would work?

So the final result becomes

```
<Elements>
   <e1>
      <e2>
         <String>Some Blabla</String>
      </e2>
      <e2>
         <String>Some other Blabla</String>
      </e2>
      <e5>
         <String>Some more Blabla</String>
      </e5>
   </e1>
</Elements>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ElementBegin">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#60;', @value,'&#62;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ElementEnd">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#60;/', @value,'&#62;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation:**

```
 <xsl:template match="ElementBegin">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#60;', @value,'&#62;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:template>
```

The above template creates a new open tag with element name as @value, 

Example: `<e1>`

And..

```
<xsl:template match="ElementEnd">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#60;/', @value,'&#62;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

This code creates a new closed tag with element name as value of attribute value.

Example:`</e1>`

So your output XML would look like this:

```
<Elements>
   <e1>
      <e2>
         <String>Some Blabla</String>
      </e2>
      <e2>
         <String>Some other Blabla</String>
      </e2>
      <e5>
         <String>Some more Blabla</String>
      </e5>
   </e1>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Using <xsl:element name="{@value}"> would be much better

Comment: @ljdelight, That wouldn't work! You don't want to close the tag right when `<ElementBegin>` closes! but when `<ElementEnd>` closes (or appears)..

Comment: ahha, i see what you did! My mistake

Comment: This solution works in this case, but you might want to avoid making a habit of [(mis)using `disable-output-escaping`](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html#d3706e225) in this way.

Comment: I tried your code @EeroHelenius, it worked fine! Since it is just a sample XML, I wanted to try on a nested one.. SO I added one more `<ElementBegin value="e0">` tag in the very beginning .. and `<ElementEnd value="e0">` in the very end. Your code didn't work! I also tried adding `<ElementBegin value="e1">` and `<ElementEnd value="e1">` additional tags.. it messed up the output.. I am not so good at generate-id() since there was no other better answer I suggested disable-output-escaping..

Comment: @EeroHelenius, your code handles if there is mismatch between ElementEnd and ElementBegin.. Since you ignore ElementEnd.. While my code collapses.. I am not really good at generate-id(), key features so I expect you to improve the answer to make it generic and not just limited to **sample XML**

Comment: Just try to add some more elements in hierarchy .. example.. add `<ElementBegin value="e21"/>` before and `<ElementEnd value="e21"/>` after `<String>Some Blabla</String>` element in input XML and observe the behavior. I am sure you can come up with reliable answer ..

Comment: @geekworking: I don't think you adding random elements to the input XML and then pointing out that my code doesn't work anymore is the way things work. The purpose of my answer was to illustrate a principle, not to provide code that can account for every possible element you can think to add in the input XML. I can only work with the input XML I was given. There's no way I can go around guessing what someone might possibly add in the input tree and write my code on that basis. That's not to say my answer couldn't be improved; I'm certain it can.

Comment: @EeroHelenius, agreed.. [15chars]

Answer (score 3):

Simply renaming elements with XSLT does not require regular expressions. You can simply do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Drop @value attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="@value"/>

  <!-- Rename <ElementBegin> and <ElementEnd> -->
  <xsl:template match="ElementBegin | ElementEnd">
    <!-- Use the value of the @value attribute as the new element name -->
    <xsl:element name="{@value}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, there's a bit of a discrepancy between your input XML and what you'd like to achieve. Using the stylesheet above will yield this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Elements>
<e1/>
 <e2/>
  <String>Some Blabla</String>
 <e2/>
 <e2/>
  <String>Some other Blabla</String>
 <e2/>
 <e5/>
  <String>Some more Blabla</String>
 <e5/>
<e1/>
</Elements>
```

Which, I think, is not quite what you're looking for. To achieve the proper nesting, you'll need a stylesheet that's a bit more complicated. Something like this should work (XSLT1.0 compatible):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Copy <String> elements as is -->
  <xsl:template match="String">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Elements">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Apply the first <ElementBegin> element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ElementBegin[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ElementBegin">
    <!-- Use the value of the @value attribute as the new element name -->
    <xsl:element name="{@value}">
      <!--
      Apply String elements whose first preceding <ElementBegin>
      sibling is the current element
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::String
        [preceding-sibling::ElementBegin[1]
          [generate-id() = generate-id(current())]]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
  Process <ElementBegin value="e1">. You could also use "ElementBegin[1]".
  -->
  <xsl:template match="ElementBegin[@value = 'e1']">
    <xsl:element name="{@value}">
      <!-- Apply all following <ElementBegin> siblings -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ElementBegin"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Drop <ElementEnd> elements -->
  <xsl:template match="ElementEnd"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Elements>
  <e1>
    <e2>
      <String>Some Blabla</String>
    </e2>
    <e2>
      <String>Some other Blabla</String>
    </e2>
    <e5>
      <String>Some more Blabla</String>
    </e5>
  </e1>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Clever. I almost had it, but the non-distinct value attributes had me stumped. I'll remember this trick

Answer (score 2):

I don't know xslt, but a regex can do this task pretty easily.  Here is an example using Perl syntax:

```
s|<ElementBegin value="(\w+)"/>|<$1>|g;
s|<ElementEnd value="(\w+)"/>|</$1>|g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex one-liner that combines the Begin and End:

`<Element(?|Begin[^"]+"(\w+)"\/()|End[^"]+"(\w+)"(\/))` and replace with `<\2\1`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/nA9rA8